# Push an extra page to history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

is it possible to push an extra page to the user's history?

Example:
We have a public marketplace, and a carousel of top 10 resources. The flow I would try to accomplish is as such

Main page(holds the top10 resources carousel) -> click on resource -> push public marketplace to the user's history (without the user landing on the page) -> user lands on the resource details.

User clicks back from the resource page-> he goes to public marketplace -> clicks back -> lands on the main page again

The reason why this is a little odd is because I'm redoing the landing pages for my company in React, but the public marketplace is on another server, and I can't really alter the logic of the public marketplace itself. I'm pretty sure the answer will be no, but the hope lives on :)

Comment: The question is too broad, and a web search with your question title yields immediately useful results.

Comment: Sorry :') I couldn't find anything for react-router, and I searched for a bit but couldn't find anything pertinent to my case. I'll do another search then :/ guess I'll try harder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in javascipt with history methods and onpopstate event.

See doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

For exemple, you can use this code when the user click on a ressource

```
history.pushState({}, "marketplace", "markeplace.html");
window.location.href = 'ressource.html';
```

You can also use replaceState and pushState when user arrive on a ressource, but you will use the onpopstate event too :

```
history.replaceState({}, "marketplace", "markeplace.html");
history.pushState({}, "ressource", "ressource.html");

window.addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {
    document.location.href = document.location;
}, false);
```